# Android async task usage

Tags: android, asynchronous, task

On click of a button, I want to open a dialog box. On that dialog box I want to set the text dynamically (somewhat like a stopwatch) with the text which will come via a loop. Could someone please guide me with sample code? I tried many examples given on the net but not able to successfully achieve the result.

```
//Button where the action starts
public void onClickStart(View v) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    dialog.setTitle("Your Step Details");
    dialog.show();
    DisplayTask dd= new DisplayTask();
    dd.execute();
}

public void doWork(){
        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable (){
            boolean isRunning=true;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(isRunning){
                    try{
                        handler.post(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try{
                                    TextView txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLeft);
                                        Date dt = new Date();
                                        int hours = dt.getHours();
                                        int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                                        int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                                        String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                                        txtCurrentTime.setText(curTime);
                                }catch (Exception e) {}

                            }

                        });
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }

            }

        }).start();
    }



public class DisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void> {


    protected void onPostExecute(){
        MainActivity main= new Mai`enter code here`nActivity();
        main.doWork();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        onPostExecute();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: On click of button, I called up a method. There I opened up my dialog box. That dialog box has two text boxes. I want to set the text with a dynamic text(lets say time). I created a asyncTask class and from onPostExecute(), I called the method where I was updating the textBox. But its not working

Comment: Can you post your code?  Then we might be able to see what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something on a timer, AsyncTask isn't the right method.  Use a Handler, and post a message to it using postMessageDelayed.  This will let you do something in a few milliseconds/seconds, but it will happen on the UI thread.

Comment: I dont want the timer. Actually I want that textbox to display something which will be polled from my DB. BUt that should be displayed on the dialogbox as my dialog box contains the textbox.

Comment: So all you need to do is call setText on the textview in the dialog.  Just make sure its done on the UI thread.